# CS 50 Edges filter

Tags: c, cs50

Could someone tell me where in my code I made a mistake? The values are failing check50. The loops seem to be correct, I really can't tell where the problem is.

I've looked at https://medium.com/swlh/cs50-pset-4-filter-8cbf734b0dbc and the code seems pretty much the same...

Thank you so much!

https://pastebin.com/MkZPFbEK

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
// for pixels at the border, treat value as B.G.R value as 0
// compute gx and gy for each value of B, G, R
// square root of gx and gy squared
 
    RGBTRIPLE tempstore[height][width];
 
    int Gx[3][3] = {
                    {-1, 0 , 1},
                    {-2, 0 , 2},
                    {-1, 0 , 1}
                    };
 
    int Gy[3][3] = {
                    {-2, -1 , -1},
                    {0, 0 , 0},
                    {2, -1 , 1}
                    };
 
 
    // for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i = i + 1)
        {
            // for each column
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j = j + 1)
            {
                // float horvalueB=0;
                // float horvalueG=0;
                // float horvalueR=0;
 
                // float vertvalueB=0;
                // float vertvalueG=0;
                // float vertvalueR=0;
                float sumhorB=0;
                float sumhorG=0;
                float sumhorR=0;
 
                float sumvertB=0;
                float sumvertG=0;
                float sumvertR=0;
 
                // check if height of neighbor cell
                for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k = k + 1)
                {
                        for (int l = -1; l <= 1; l = l + 1)
                        {
                           int htcheck = i + k;
                           int wdcheck = j + l;
                            // check if height of neighbor cell is within bounds
                            if (((htcheck) >= 0) && ((htcheck) < height))
                            {
                                // check if width of neighbor cell is within bounds
                                if (((wdcheck) >= 0) && ((wdcheck) < width))
                                {
                                    sumhorB += image[htcheck][wdcheck].rgbtBlue * Gx[k+1][l+1];
                                    sumhorG += image[htcheck][wdcheck].rgbtGreen * Gx[k+1][l+1];
                                    sumhorR += image[htcheck][wdcheck].rgbtRed * Gx[k+1][l+1];
 
                                    sumvertB += image[htcheck][wdcheck].rgbtBlue * Gy[k+1][l+1];
                                    sumvertG += image[htcheck][wdcheck].rgbtGreen * Gy[k+1][l+1];
                                    sumvertR += image[htcheck][wdcheck].rgbtRed * Gy[k+1][l+1];
 
                                    // sumhorB = sumhorB + horvalueB;
                                    // sumhorG = sumhorG + horvalueG;
                                    // sumhorR = sumhorR + horvalueR;
 
                                    // sumvertB = sumvertB + vertvalueB;
                                    // sumvertG = sumvertG + vertvalueG;
                                    // sumvertR = sumvertR + vertvalueR;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                int blue = round(sqrt( sumhorB*sumhorB + sumvertB*sumhorB ));
                int green = round(sqrt( sumhorG*sumhorG + sumvertG*sumhorG ));
                int red = round(sqrt( sumhorR*sumhorR + sumvertR*sumhorR ));
 
                // Cap at 255
                if (red > 255)
                {
                    red = 255;
                }
                if (green > 255)
                {
                    green = 255;
                }
                if (blue > 255)
                {
                    blue = 255;
                }            // Assign new values to pixels
                tempstore[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
                tempstore[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;
                tempstore[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
 
            }
        }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i = i + 1)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j = j + 1)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = tempstore[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = tempstore[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = tempstore[i][j].rgbtRed;
        }
    }
 
    return;
}
```

Comment: You need to use your debugger first before asking help on StackOverflow.

Comment: The content of `Gy` does not look OK.

Comment: Ah yes thank you, totally missed that... I fixed it but the values are still wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Ahh.... The problem is I was multiplying the wrong things... Sorry about it. Was multiplying sumvert with sumhor...

```
            int blue = round(sqrt( (sumhorB*sumhorB) + (sumvertB*sumhorB) ));
            int green = round(sqrt( (sumhorG*sumhorG) + (sumvertG*sumhorG) ));
            int red = round(sqrt( (sumhorR*sumhorR) + (sumvertR*sumhorR) ));
```

Should be

```
            int blue = round(sqrt( (sumhorB*sumhorB) + (sumvertB*sumvertB) ));
            int green = round(sqrt( (sumhorG*sumhorG) + (sumvertG*sumvertG) ));
            int red = round(sqrt( (sumhorR*sumhorR) + (sumvertR*sumvertR) ));
```